# Using a C++ DLL (from V.S. 2015), how would I attach a window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

So, recently I have gotten into coding. However, the type of programming I want to do would require heavy knowledge of reverse engineering- exploiting a games flaws. I want to be a penetration tester. My problem is that when I build the DLL solution, and inject into a random process (e.g. notepad, using Extreme Injector) no menu pops up. I believe it has something to do with the following error; however, after heavy research, I turn up nothing. Could someone link me to a viable source explaining the error, and what causes it?

[The error:](https://gyazo.com/ae92e00aefbac3702bc75df369ccb188)
[image]

I'm not sure what is wrong with this. However, I have noticed that this occurred sometime after I put it into the editor- it was NOT there at the start. I believe I may have modified something which broke it.

The code can be found below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define MYMENU_EXIT (WM_APP + 101)
#define MYMENU_MESSAGEBOX (WM_APP + 102) 

HINSTANCE  inj_hModule;
HWND       prnt_hWnd;

LRESULT CALLBACK DLLWindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

BOOL RegisterDLLWindowClass(wchar_t szClassName[]) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.hInstance = inj_hModule;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)L"InjectedDLLWindowClass";
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)szClassName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DLLWindowProc;
    wc.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        return 0;
    }
}

HMENU CreateDLLWindowMenu() {
    HMENU hMenu;
    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hMenuPopup;
    if (hMenu == NULL) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hMenuPopup = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(hMenuPopup, MF_STRING, MYMENU_EXIT, TEXT("Exit"));
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenuPopup, TEXT("File"));

    hMenuPopup = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(hMenuPopup, MF_STRING, MYMENU_MESSAGEBOX, TEXT("MessageBox"));
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hMenuPopup, TEXT("Test"));
    return hMenu;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParam) {
    MSG messages;
    wchar_t *pString = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t * > (lpParam);
    HMENU hMenu = CreateDLLWindowMenu();
    RegisterDLLWindowClass(L"InjectedDLLWindowClass");
    prnt_hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"ROBLOX");
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"InjectedDLLWindowClass", pString, 
        WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 300, 
        prnt_hWnd, hMenu, inj_hModule, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return 1;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK DLLWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam) {
        case MYMENU_EXIT:
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            break;
        case MYMENU_MESSAGEBOX:
            MessageBox(hwnd, L"Test", L"MessageBox", MB_OK);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        inj_hModule = hModule;
        CreateThread(0, NULL, ThreadProc, (LPVOID)L"Agsploit - [By: Agluk15]", NULL, NULL);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Code didn't format right. New to this. Sorry!

Comment: after `ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` add `UpdateWindow(hwnd);`

Comment: also, you're not checking for errors, almost every call to system function can fail, add some kind of alert on it

Comment: Heavenly. Thank you!

Comment: Don't post error messages as screenshots. This will not be easily discoverable in text searches, making your question less useful to other readers.

Comment: Sorry about that, should have thought it through. Not sure about the terminology for this, but hopefully you can understand me: how can I create a button like not on the title bar, but down below it, that says "execute" in the bottom right corner?

Comment: I created one but for some reason it does not appear.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed create GUI thread on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` in `DllMain` entry point. The error you are getting seems to be Visual Studio link error, perhaps from a separate EXE project. And you try call `DllMain` directly. You should start with something much simpler. Lookup `__declspec(dllexport)/dllimport` and create DLL file, access it from your own EXE file.

Comment: The error message suggests that you have defined two `DllMain` functions in your source files, remove one and the error should disappear.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Calling `CreateThread` from `DllMain` is fine, if you do not synchronize with other threads (see [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx)).